# How a compiled XSLT works on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, xslt

My XSLT was compiled via xsltc, the performance is hugely improved. However, I am wondering how the compiled XSLT works on IIS? Will there any cached of the compiled XSLT instance on the IIS after 1st JIT'ing. As I am seeing my page slightly slow in response from server, but if the page after being called once, subsequent access to the page will faster. So I am suspecting all the transformation processes was not cached for long time on server side.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, that your experience with slow response for first page loading can be mainly depend on effect of "pool recycling" which is used in IIS. All loaded assemblies for your application are being cleared from memory if you don't send any request to IIS (default time is 20 minutes). Then when you do your first request on server after this pause, your application is starting and it takes rather significant time. For IIS 7.5 is developed "Warm up module". You can reed about it here: http://www.iis.net/download/applicationwarmup.
If you experience such effect with loading not only first page on all site after period of time of inactivity, but for every new page of the site. In this way the probable explanation of such effect is that for other pages your browser simply use cache. (IE for example is crazy in caching)